# Is it possible to redownload all failed images on the page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes, upon certain conditions (for example, using VPN or Proxy) not all images can be donwloaded for pages. These images are looking like empty squares with crosses etc. (failed to download images). Though, I am completely sure, that these images exist on server. Because, if try to update page or press F5, images can suddenly appear. So there can be a situation, when all images were downloaded correctly, and situation, when some of them were not downloaded.

Is there some certain way to force browser to check, if image was downloaded correctly, and if not - redownload it?

This is what I tried

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('div[class*="image"]').each(function() {

    var tempHTML = $(this).html();
    tempHTML = tempHTML.replace(/.png/g, '.png?' + new Date().getTime());
    $(this).html(tempHTML);
});
}, 3000);
```

Upon some timeout it tries to add current date to the name of the image (its extension) and sometimes it helps, but not always.

And I still don't know, how can I check, that image was downloaded (not failed "crossed")

Comment: img element has a `onerror` attribute in which you can pass a function. This would be called when the image download fails. You can make a note of the img element that failed and then trto change the source with your new time to trigger the re-download

Comment: Your regex is wrong. You need to escape the `.` to select a dot instead of any character. `\.`

Comment: Unless your webserver or connection is faulty a retry will not help. It is more likely the images are getting blocked. Your web server is very unreliable if it requires an image onerror for each image. http is a very reliable transport protocol with multiple levels of redundancy built in. It can transport files reliably over a very bad connection. You should not have to implement image error detection in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the onerror event to try to reload the image.

```
<img src="some_image.png" onerror="reloadImage(this);" />

function reloadImage(event) {
    // Refresh the src attribute, which should make the
    // browsers reload the iamge.
    event.src = event.src;
}
```

Even though the event is not a part of any standard,it works in every browser since IE5.